# Can we plot percentage with Plot_ly

Tags: r

is there a way to plot percentages using plot_ly. For example, the below is used to plot the count of cut from diamonds dataset,

```
plot_ly(diamonds, x = ~cut)
```

[image]

But i tried to plot the percentage for cut. For example I need the percentage of "Good" to the total count. Is there a way to get it?

Answer (score 0):

It could be done like this. 
First, create percentage for each cut category

```
diamonds %>% group_by(cut) %>% summarize(perc = n()/53940*100)
```

[summarized dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5a93.png)

Second, pipe the resultant data set to plot_ly()

```
diamonds %>% group_by(cut) %>% summarize(perc = n()/53940*100) %>% plot_ly(x = ~cut, y = ~perc)
```

[R Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01P8X.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data.table` and `ggplot2`:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

dt <- data.table(diamonds)
```

#### Calculate the number of records by each cut, and then calculate the `prop.table` of those counts:

```
result <- dt[, .N, by = cut][, .(cut, N, percentCut = prop.table(N))]
```

#### Now you can plot it with `ggplot` and use the library `scales` to have a beautiful percent-formatted y-axis:

```
p <- ggplot(result, aes(x = cut, y = percentCut))+
        geom_col()+
        scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

#### Now you can pass `p` to plotly, if so you want:

```
plotly::ggplotly(p)
```